# Velocity applied to object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game with similar mechanics to the blue bird in angry birds (splits into 3 and the clones follow a trajectory with the same direction and velocity as the initial one). how can I apply the velocity to the other clones in the same direction?

```
_spawnpoint1edit.Set(0,+2,0);
_spawnpoint2edit.Set(0,0,0);
_spawnpoint3edit.Set(0,-2,0);

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && 
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.magnitude > 2 && 
    _activated == false)
    {
        _activated = true;
        Debug.Log("Ability Activated");

        _spawnpoint1 = transform.position + _spawnpoint1edit;
        _spawnpoint2 = transform.position + _spawnpoint2edit;
        _spawnpoint3 = transform.position + _spawnpoint3edit;

        var clone1 = Instantiate (_prefab1, transform.position + 
            _spawnpoint1edit , Quaternion.identity);
        var clone2 = Instantiate (_prefab2, transform.position + 
            _spawnpoint2edit , Quaternion.identity);
        var clone3 = Instantiate (_prefab3, transform.position + 
            _spawnpoint3edit , Quaternion.identity);
```

I still want to write some code to delete the initial bird, so I'll end up with 3 clones. and I need help with transferring the initial bird's velocity to these 3 clones.

I'm thinking of saving it in a variable and then applying it to the clones but I can't think of a way to work it out.

Comment: [What have you tried, show us your code, give us some diagrams, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: why use 3 different prefabs? and well what is your object? is it a Rigidbody so you can easily access the velocity?

Comment: yes, it is a rigidbody2d, and I'm using 3 objects because each one has its own position... isn't that the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;

    public void Split()
    {
        float offset = 1;
        Rigidbody2D rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        GameObject clone1 = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + Vector3.up * offset, transform.rotation);
        GameObject clone2 = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        GameObject clone3 = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position + Vector3.up * offset * -1, transform.rotation);

        clone1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = rb.velocity;
        clone2.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = rb.velocity;
        clone3.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = rb.velocity;
    }
}
```

When you instantiate an object, it copies it, not just inserts it into the game, you you can have only one prefab and use it multiple times. I hope this solves your problem.